# Scala Option[Enum] matching is not working as expected

Tags: scala, enums

I've got a legacy Scala app where we use Enums (so I don't really have the option to change to case classes). I'm having issues with the following function:

```
def mapFamily(assetMetadata: AssetMetadata): String = {
  assetMetadata.family match {
    case None => throw InvalidAssetFamilyException("Family is required")
    case Some(EnumFamily.Inside) => "1"
    case Some(EnumFamily.Outside) => "2"
    case unknown => throw InvalidFamilyException(s"Unknown Family: $unknown.")
  }
```

`assetMetadat.family` is an `Option[EnumFamily.Family]`

The enum looks like the following:

```
object EnumFamily extends Enumeration {
  type Family = Value
  val Inside = Value("Inside")
  val Outside = Value("Outside")
}
```

When I try calling `mapFamily` I always get the unknown/exception case with a message like so:

```
Unknown Family: Some(Inside)
```

Why is it not matching correctly?

Comment: I think the problem is with `case Some(Family.Inside) => "1"` because it should be `case Some(EnumFamily.Inside) => "1"`

Comment: Sorry @TheKojuEffect, that's the way it was (I renamed some things before posting and screwed up on that). I've edited the code to reflect that.

Comment: What's the version of scala that you are using, it's working as expected with scala `2.11.8`.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this is question is totally invalid. My issue was due to de-serialization. The version of json4s we're using (yes, it's legacy. Never use json4s ever) actually de-serialized it into the wrong enum with similar attributes (and somehow reflectively defeating all the type-checking).

I'll leave this question up, but if you've arrived here, are you using a serializer? Use your debugger and see if you're getting back the types you expect.